# It is possible to add an offset at the top of scrollbar without using javascript?

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

I wanted to create a space between the top of the viewport and the top-tip of the scrollbar though CSS, in my case it is a google map with infowindow(with Infobox extension) when the scrollbar appears, the "x" close button overlapped the scrollbar, see the image below[image]

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by using this rule

```
body div#map-canvas ::-webkit-scrollbar-button:start:decrement
{
    display: block;
    height: 19px; // This will add the top offset 
    background-color: transparent;
}
```